# sum of transfers with conversion in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table that saves customers transfers. I want an sql query that gets the total amount of transfers in base currency.For example , if the transfer was made in dollars , i have to get this amount in the base currency. I have another table that stores currencies and handles the conversion rates between the currencies.
How can i get the sum of transfers in the base currency using  a single sql query?

The tables are as follows

1. Transfer(transfer_id , trf_type , currency (references currency) , amount)
2. Currency (Currency , Rate) Where rate refers to the base currency

Here's what i tried but without handling currency conversion:

```
Select 
Case
When transfer.trf_type = 'I' then 'Transfer From the inside'
When transfer.trf_type = 'o' then 'Transfer fom the outside'

End AS type ,
Count(transfer.trf_type) ,
Sum(transfer.amount)
From transfer
Group By transfer.trf_type
```

How can i do this? The output of the above query is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? But in general you are looking for a join between the table `transfer` and the table that stores the conversion rates

Comment: Tag the proper DBMS and provide some sample data.

Comment: Also: please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I am using Postgresql , i can join the two tables but i need the currency conversion in the transfer

Comment: @AbdallaIsmail what is name of table which stores currency conversion rate? which is joining column between two(common column) tables?

Comment: the table transfer has a field currency which is a foreign key for table currency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    case
        when transfer.trf_type = 'I' then 'Transfer From the inside'
        when transfer.trf_type = 'o' then 'Transfer fom the outside'
    end AS type,
    count(transfer.trf_type),
    sum(transfer.amount * currency.rate)
from transfer
inner join currency using(currency)
group By transfer.trf_type;
```